# MVC3 Pass viewmodel object with Iqueryable back to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a view that I pass a viewmodel object to that contains an IQueryable<> object.

This object is used to populate an mvccontrib grid.  The view also contains other partial views that allow the user to filter the data within the grid.

Once the grid is filtered I would like the user to be able to export the Iqueryable object to another controller actionresult method which then calls another viewmodel that exports the data to Excel.

Here is the snippet of the view that calls the Export actionresult() method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { Model }))
{
  <p>
   <input class="button" value="Export to Excel" type="submit" />
  </p>
```

}

Model does contain the IQueryable object.

When I debug the code I can view the viewmodel object,  and of course in order to populate the IQueryable I must enumerate the object.

I have also created another viewmodel object that,  once the Model object is passed back to the actionresult method attempts to enumerate the IQueryable object by either using the .ToList() method or the AsEnumerable() method.

But in all cases the IQueryable object is pass to the controller as a null object.

Here is the action result method that is being called from the view:

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Export(PagedViewModel<NPSProcessed> NPSData)
{
    string message = "";
    NPSData Query = new Models.NPSData(NPSData);

    Query.IData = NPSData.Query.ToList();

        // Opening the Excel template...
        FileStream fs =
        new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"\Content\NPSProcessedTemplate.xls"),         FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        ee.ExportData(fs, ms, Query.IData, message);

        // Sending the server processed data back to the user computer...
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "NPSProcessedNewFile.xls"); 

    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass complex objects around like this: `new { Model }`. It would have been to easy :-). You will have to send them one by one:

```
new { prop1 = Model.Prop1, prop2 = Model.Prop2, ... }
```

Obviously this could get quite painful. So what I would recommend you is to send only an id:

```
new { id = Model.id }
```

and then inside your controller action that is supposed to export to Excel use this id to fetch the object from wherever you fetched it initially in the GET action (presumably a database or something). If you want to preserve the paging, and stuff that the user could have performed on the grid, you could send them as well to the server:

```
new { id = Model.id, page = Model.CurrentPage, sortColumn = Model.SortBy }
```

Another possibility (which I don't recommend) consists into saving this object into the session so that you can fetch it back later.

Yet another possibility (which I still don't recommend) is to use the MVCContrib's Html.Serialize helper which allows you to serialize an entire object graph into a hidden field and it will be sent to the server when the form is submitted and you will be able to fetch it as action argument.

Comment: Good answers,  I have tried new {prop1 = Model.Query}.  Model.Query is the IQueryable object.  I get the following error: Cannot create an instance of an interface.

Comment: @Joe Pitz, no, only simple types (strings, integers, ...). Don't try to send any complex objects. It won't work.

Comment: If the users select several hundred rows, then what would be the best way to pass this data back to the model.  Would passing the filter parameters selected by the users, and then using those parameters in the Export model to re-create the filter condition on the data table be the best way?  Thanks

Comment: @Joe Pitz, only pass the ids of those selected rows. Then on the server fetch the corresponding data from the data store using those ids.

Comment: as a test I attempted to pass a string as new {prop1 = "test"}  the actionresult still sees a null value.  This view contains several {Html.RenderPartial();} methods.  In one of the partial views there is also a using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)).  Could this be part of the problem?  If so how can I solve,  Thanks for all of the help.  Joe

Comment: I see that your controller action takes some `PagedViewModel<NPSProcessed>`. You haven't shown what this beast looks like, but if you do `new {prop1 = "test"}`, make sure that this object has a property called `prop1`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: don't put IQueryable properties in your model.  The model should be purely simple objects and validation attributes.  Keep the queryability in your controller.

Comment: then how do I pass the data from the data table to the mvccontrib grid? The lateness of the IQueryable, from what I understand, allows the paging to occur in the grid?  What would you recommend as the best solution to get data from the model or controller to the view and back again?

Comment: Keep it simple; send your data as an IList<> of objects, store changes in a simple JSON string for persistence or update via AJAX.  In my experience, the MvcContrib grid is more pain than it's worth the moment you want to do something even slightly custom.  (Personal opinion)

Comment: To be clear: feel free to send the collections to the view; don't try to get them back from the view.